# How to configure php and java application same host

Tags: java, php, apache

I have two application one is working in php another is working in jetty server . i want configure in to Apache so i have write code in httpd conf file
                           so i have write this code but it is not working properly

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ErrorLog logs/dev.mapmyindia.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common


     ProxyRequests     off
     ProxyPreserveHost on
     ProxyPass /directionapp/ http://localhost:8989/index.html/
     ProxyPassReverse /directionapp/ http://localhost:8989/index.html/


<Directory /var/www/html/example.com>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all  
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/rim/>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
#        Allow from 122.160.188.70 122.180.97.58
        Allow from all
        #Allow from 122.160.188.70
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Assign different port to PHP project. For example 81

Comment: @ Asad i did not change port . can you give idea to rewrite url  to sloved problem

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346872/two-different-languages-php-and-java-on-same-application-with-php-on-apache-and

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this document https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/HTTPServer

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
```

...

ProxyPreserveHost On

ServerName www.stackoverflow.com

ProxyPass  /excluded !

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/

ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `mod_proxy` to do this with `Jetty`. [Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Apache) is the clean configuration details.

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule jk_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_jk.so
```